# Player 'Helias' (1) discovered unknown area (x: y: z: map: )

Tags: world-of-warcraft, azerothcore

I added a new world map on WoW-wotlk (Battle for Gilneas map id: `761`) and I get this error in the server console:

`Player 'Helias' (1) discovered unknown area (x: y: z: map: )`

Screen of the server log:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue extracting correctly the dbc & maps.

I missed some `AreaTable.dbc` data, I added them, (re)extracted the maps and solved the problem.

To extract a custom maps from my client I added renamed my MPQ patch into `patch-enUS-4.MPQ` (case sensitive) and put it in `WoW/Data/enUS/` directory because the mapextractor don't read any *.MPQ files but only some of them.

**If the problem still persist**
Check your map area files, probably in the ADT file you associated a different Area ID than your `AreaTable.dbc` (`ID`).